# How to display the complete week in a table for a month

Tags: javascript, java, html

I have a requirement where I need to display the complete week (4-5 weeks) for a month. i.e. if a month begins with Friday(1st of Jan) it should still display in the same week. But in my case, it is not happening like that. As 1st of Jan starts from Friday, it is showing as a separate week.

As you can see in both the fiddles, Dec 31 is Thursday and Jan 1st is Friday. But since Jan 1st is a separate month, it is showing as a different week from Friday. But I don't want this to happen. I want all my week to display in a single table.

What changes should I make in my logic to make it correct? Where have I gone wrong? what logic should I add aside my while loop for it to display the entire week? Please help me.

Comment: Are sure you copied all your source code for the method? Because you only handle mondays and sundays in your code above. You have an `if` for sundays and an `else if` for mondays. Shouldn't there be an else statement for the other days? It won't solve your problem, it just helps us to help.

Comment: Is it `Java` or `JavaScript`?

Comment: Could you  Share the code

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is excluding the rest of the days of a week because you've only included items that belong to the month you've prescribed.

```
while (c.get(Calendar.MONTH) == month) {
    ....
}
```

You should add some logic within to check if the last 'week' has 7 days in it and if not then add the missing items.

Comment: where exactly should i write my logic?